# How to insert a value in a Dataframe for Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm a new programmer and just started learning a little bit about numpy. I want to insert the information from web scraping into a data frame. Here is what I have came up with so far.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import numpy as np
import pandas as  pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame


my_url = 'http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=laptops&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"row"})


DF_obj = DataFrame(np.arange(len(containers)*2).reshape((len(containers),2)), columns = ['Name', 'Price'])#index=['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6'], columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3', 'column 4', 'column 5', 'column 6', ]

#print(DF_obj)
for container in containers:


   try:
      title_container = container.find_all("h4")
      product_name = title_container[0].text

      price_container = container.find_all("div", {"class", "pb-hero-price pb-purchase-price"})
      product_price = price_container[0].text
      #print("Product Name: "+ product_name)
      #print("Price:"+ product_price)
      DF_obj['Name'] = product_name # Here is the problem
      DF_obj['Price'] = product_price# Here is the problem
   except Exception:
       pass

print(DF_obj)
```

What I'm doing now will only allow the last scraped product to be displayed. This is because I'm making the product name and price to equal the whole column. I want to find a way to make it only equal to the i'th column and the iterate to the next one.

So basically, I want to insert a value on (container,1) and (container, 2). Since container will iterate the next name will go onto the next column. What would be the syntax to do this?

Here are some of the outputs to let you guys visualize what is going on:

```
  Name    Price
0   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
1   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
2   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
3   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
4   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
5   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
6   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
7   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
8   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
9   Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
10  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
11  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
12  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
13  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
14  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
15  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...  $849.99
```

Cut some of the output since you get the idea...

Here is what I want except inside the data frame.

```
Product Name: Dell - XPS 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Core i7 - 16GB Memory - 512GB Solid State Drive - Silver
Price:$241.99
Product Name: HP - 15.6" Laptop - AMD A6-Series - 4GB Memory - 500GB Hard Drive - Black
Price:$241.99
Product Name: Dell - Inspiron 15.6" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Core i3 - 6GB Memory - 1TB Hard Drive - Black
Price:$349.99
Product Name: HP - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i5 - 8GB Memory - 2TB Hard Drive - Textured linear gradient grooves in black
Price:$449.99
Product Name: Lenovo - Ideapad 110s 11.6" Laptop - Intel Celeron - 2GB Memory - 32GB eMMC Flash Memory - White
Price:$169.99
Product Name: HP - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i5 - 8GB Memory - 1TB Hard Drive - HP finish in jet black
Price:$399.99
Product Name: Lenovo - Flex 4 14 2-in-1 14" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Pentium - 4GB Memory - 500GB Hard Drive - Black
Price:$349.99
Product Name: Lenovo - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i3 - 6GB Memory - 1TB Hard Drive - Ebony black
Price:$312.99
Product Name: Lenovo - Flex 4 1130 2-in-1 11.6" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Celeron - 2GB Memory - 64GB eMMC Flash Memory
Price:$229.99
Product Name: HP - Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Core i7 - 8GB Memory - 256GB Solid State Drive - Natural silver
Price:$1,129.99
```

Thx.

Comment: Can you share some sample data with us?

Comment: By sample data do you mean the output(Sorry I'm really really new in this). Let me enter the outputs on the main post. Here is the website I'm trying to scrape data from:http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=laptops&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code. The list of containers wasn't exactly right. The div tag for `class=row` was a little further up what what you needed. Now the for loop with iterate over all the `list-item` tags and add them row by row to the data frame.

```
my_url = 'http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=laptops&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#This is the div tag that contains each of the products listed on the page
containers = page_soup.find_all("div",{'class':'list-item'})

#Just a check to make sure all the products are found
print len(containers)

#Create an empty dataframe, It can be populated later, no need for a fixed 
#structure
DF_obj = DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Price'])


#we want to loop over the containers, but during each loop, we also want to 
#track the loop number we are on, this will help us enter data into the 
#dataframe, so we wrap containers with enumerate()

# in this situation index = loop count, container = value from containers list
for index,container in enumerate(containers):
   try:
      #These two you provided
      title_container = container.find_all("h4")
      price_container = container.find_all("div", {"class", "pb-hero-price pb-purchase-price"})

      #Now that we found the info, we insert it into the data frame. This 
      #can be done with DF_obj.loc[row#,column Name], and our df is updated
      #for every container
      DF_obj.loc[index,'Name'] = title_container[0].text
      DF_obj.loc[index, 'Price'] = price_container[0].text
   except Exception:
       pass
print DF_obj
```

and dataframe

```
                                                 Name      Price
0   HP - 15.6" Laptop - AMD A6-Series - 4GB Memory...    $241.99
1   HP - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i5 - 8GB Memory...    $399.99
2   Lenovo - Ideapad 110s 11.6" Laptop - Intel Cel...    $169.99
3   Dell - Inspiron 15.6" Touch-Screen Laptop - In...    $349.99
4   HP - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i5 - 8GB Memory...    $449.99
5   HP - 17.3" Laptop - Intel Core i7 - 8GB Memory...    $529.99
6   Dell - Inspiron 11.6" Laptop - Intel Celeron -...    $174.99
7   Lenovo - 15.6" Laptop - AMD A6-Series - 4GB Me...    $229.99
8   Dell - Inspiron 15.6" Touch-Screen Laptop - In...    $349.99
9   Lenovo - Flex 4 14 2-in-1 14" Touch-Screen Lap...    $349.99
10  Dell - Inspiron 17.3" Laptop - AMD A9-Series -...    $506.99
11  Dell - Inspiron 17.3" Laptop - Intel Core i7 -...    $938.99
12  Samsung - 11.6" Chromebook - Intel Celeron - 4...        NaN
13  Acer - 15.6" Chromebook - Intel Celeron - 4GB ...    $219.99
14  Lenovo - Yoga 710 2-in-1 11.6" Touch-Screen La...    $399.99
15  Dell - Inspiron 2-in-1 17.3" Touch-Screen Lapt...    $849.99
16  HP - Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen La...  $1,279.99
17  Asus - 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen Laptop - Inte...  $1,129.99
18  HP - 15.6" Laptop - AMD A12-Series - 6GB Memor...    $299.99
19  Asus - ROG GL502VM 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i...  $1,149.99
20  Lenovo - 15.6" Laptop - Intel Core i3 - 6GB Me...    $312.99
21  Lenovo - Flex 4 1130 2-in-1 11.6" Touch-Screen...    $229.99
22  Samsung - 12.3" Chromebook Plus - Touch Screen...    $399.00
23  HP - Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.3" Touch-Screen La...  $1,129.99
```

Comment: Sure, I updated the code with comments explaining what is being done, if you have any more questions, you can ask them here